Can't load Hive transactional table into dataframe using Spark2
I'm trying to load a hive transactional table into a PySpark dataframe, but receive the error:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o086.showString.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0289756_0000"

Using SparkSession.builder and trying to load into dataframe.
Is there a way to load a transactional table into a dataframe?
Spark version: 2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8
Python version: 2.7.5
I tried loading the table using SparkSession.builder().
I was expecting it to return a DataFrame object.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(application_name) \
    .config("spark.jars", "path/to/jar") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", "database.table") \
    .options(**properties) \
    .load()

df.show()   # Returns error above every time


Are you reading the table using a schema ? can you provide us more details ? (input table schema, the spark session code + read)

Yes, fully qualified table name.
